# ReQL | RethinkDB error: Expected type TABLE but found SINGLE_SELECTION

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, reql

hello i have this in the data explorer on the webinterface but i have a error

code:

```
r.db("discordboatsclubv1").table("users").get("355995885085392896").insert({
  "admin":"true"
})
```

error:

e: Expected type TABLE but found SINGLE_SELECTION:
{
    "badges":   [],
    "createdAt":    1573923739827,
    "discordAT":    "94GXMoWf1Anhn5neKsV2o4nWS9HVFS",
    "discordRT":    "akv9HS1nY9dqP9dfXou8jpNowv2Gw5",
    "id":   "355995885085392896"
} in:
r.db("discordboatsclubv1").table("users").get("355995885085392896").insert({"admin": "true"})
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB1UI.png)

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `.get` you are accessing to a single document with that id. From there you can only insert additional element with an update statement:

```
r.db("discordboatsclubv1").table("users").get("355995885085392896").update({
  "admin":"true"
})
```

Comment: thanks it's works ! but i have another error when i go to the webpage https://imgur.com/a/3xtH9bd

Comment: what webpage are we talking about?

Comment: the website use a database so i have added a document in database to be are admin and when i go to a part i have that (i use https://github.com/discordboats-club/website)

Comment: add another question where you describe what are you trying to achieve, what tools you are using and how, and whats blocking you.

Comment: in fact after having admin on the database and going into the staff part of the site I have this error https://imgur.com/a/3xtH9bd